# Last 3 month lags in r

Tags: r

The data is :

```
Category <- c(rep("A",4))
Month <- c(1,2,3,4)
Sales <- c(10,15,20,25)

df <- data.frame(Category,Month,Sales)

df <- df %>% filter(Category=='A') %>% 
             group_by(Month) %>%
             summarise(Sales=sum(Sales,na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
             mutate(lag_1 = dplyr::lag(Sales, 1),
                    lag_2 = dplyr::lag(Sales, 2),
                    lag_3 = dplyr::lag(Sales, 3),
                    lag_3_mean = rollapply(Sales,3,mean,align='right',fill=NA))
```

Present Output
[image]

I want the lag_3_mean to be the mean of last 3 months, not including the present month. For example, in Month 4 lag_3_mean = Average(Sales value in month 3,2,1).

The expected output should be:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a width of `list(-(1:3))` to get offsets of -1, -2, -3.

```
rollapplyr(Sales, list(-(1:3)), mean, fill = NA)
```

Note that this recent question is very similar  [Variable frameshift rolling average for multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64572959/variable-frameshift-rolling-average-for-multiple-variables/64573239#64573239)